# How to change system navigationBarColor in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**How do I change system navigation bar color in jetpack compose**

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution to change the `navigationBarColor` in jetpack compose:

```
setContent {
      val window: Window = this.window
      window.navigationBarColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.toArgb()
      Surface { 
        App()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Google's Accompanist library](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/systemuicontroller) which provides utilities for updating the system UI bar colors within Compose.

Here's a sample to change the navigation bar color using this:

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
val useDarkIcons = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight

SideEffect {
    systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(
        color = Color.Transparent, //Your color
        darkIcons = useDarkIcons
    )
}
```

Documentation: https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/

Comment: Where do i put the SideEffect ?

Comment: This library is deprecated,

Comment: So what's new appraoch?

Comment: As @Dominik stated, the lib is deprecated, you might want to add the code below:
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window,false)